# How do I determine why I'm getting 503 errors on my node.js server?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am currently teaching myself node.js as a hobbyist. I have a server that I was previously able to get to work with simple 'hello world' outputs. However, I think I might have broken something in my node.js server while doing some tinkering last week and it no longer works. Unfortunately, I am not sure how to troubleshoot the answer and am hoping for direction on that.

The issue is that when I navigate to my domain I just get a 503 error.

However, when I check my node.js log file, the output is displaying my default text that the server is running.

The sample code I'm using is:

```
    // Load the http module to create an http server.
var http = require('http'),
    sys = require('sys');

// Configure our HTTP server to respond with Hello World to all requests.
var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.end("Hello World\n");
});

// Listen on port 8000, IP defaults to 127.0.0.1
server.listen(8000);

// Put a friendly message in the log
sys.puts("Server running on port 8000");
```

Can anyone help me discover the place to find more detailed reasons on why I'm getting a 503?

I looked at the error logs from apache and see this, but have no clue what it means:

```
[Fri May 30 18:12:09.658627 2014] [proxy:error] [pid 25351:tid 3071591036672] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: HTTP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:8080 (127.0.0.1) failed
[Fri May 30 18:12:09.658713 2014] [proxy:error] [pid 25351:tid 3071591036672] AH00959: ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (127.0.0.1) for 60s
[Fri May 30 18:12:09.658731 2014] [proxy_http:error] [pid 25351:tid 3071591036672] [client 128.32.70.98:19556] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: 127.0.0.1
[Fri May 30 18:12:10.096354 2014] [proxy:error] [pid 25351:tid 3071599429376] AH00940: HTTP: disabled connection for (127.0.0.1)
```

Comment: 503 is a server error, check the webserver log.

Comment: Can you revert your repo back to a working state?

Comment: Are you sure you're navigating to port 8000?

Comment: Is there something like Nginx in front, which might cause the issues? Maybe it's not your node script.

Comment: Thanks all. I added the apache logs to the OP. I don't have anything else (that I know of!) running on the server.

Comment: looks like the node.js is running on port 8000, but apache is configured to connect to port 8080

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Yup, that's what it was. Sigh. Thanks! Is there way to accept this as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your node.js is configured to listen on port 8000

```
server.listen(8000);
```

but apache is trying to connect to port 8080

```
HTTP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:8080 (127.0.0.1) failed
                                        ^
```

Configure both application to use the same port (and make sure it is not already in use).

Comment: But as far as I know, node should listen to different port to avoid performance issues and we should make reverse proxy to proxy connections go to node server location to port 8000. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar problem. It turns out that my (rust) server was using the ip6 version of localhost - ::1 rather then the ipv4 version - 127.0.0.1, but I had the latter in the Apache proxy command, so they weren't connecting.

I figured this out when I noticed that netstat didn't have my server showing as connecting to 127.0.0.1.  An extra confusion was because `curl localhost:1234` was connecting correctly. I didn't try it, but perhaps if I'd put localhost into the proxy line it would have worked, too.